# Best way to let user to configure Vim plugin

Tags: vim

I need to let the user to configure plugin setting (e.g. list of file types, that will not be processed by plugin).

The simple one option is to set a global variable in `.vimrc` and check it in the plugin.

Does more elegant/acceptable way exist or it is the only option?

**UPDATE:**
I am writting this plugin: https://github.com/aserebryakov/filestyle. What I don't want to force user to create a big amount of files in `ftplugin` without real need to configure settings for these types of files. The point is to configure it only in one place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to decide on "best" without knowing the exact context. You're right, one way is the canonical `g:PluginName_ConfigVar` variable. Even there, you have the alternative of supplying a comma-separated list (`'c,cpp,html,xhtml'`), real List (`['c', 'cpp', 'html', 'xhtml']`), or regular expression (`'^\(c\|cpp\|x\?html\)$'`).

An alternative, modular approach would be to disable the plugin when a `b:NoPluginName` buffer-local variable has been set, e.g. in `~/.vim/ftplugin/<filetype>.vim`. This would make sense when there are only few filetypes to be excepted. The nice thing about that is that though filetype-bound, it's more flexible. For example, if you wanted to turn off the plugin only for HTML files in project A, you could define an `:autocmd` or add a condition to the ftplugin to check the file's path, and then set the flag based on that. With a single global variable, this sort of excepting would be much less elegant.

Comment: Thanks for providing more background. I have a similar plugin, [IndentConsistencyCop plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1690), and decided to extract the launching part into a separate plugin, [IndentConsistencyCopAutoCmds](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1691). I wouldn't recommended this in general, but for this particular functionality, it makes sense.

Comment: Where should be `g:indentconsistencycop_filetypes` redefined in case of user wants to change default settings?

Comment: In `~/.vimrc`, or anywhere before the plugin is sourced. See, this plugin add-on implements the basic case suitable for 90% of users. The rest can leave off the add-on and build their particular infrastructure around the main plugin.